# How to handle local notification and fcm to new screen when app is in background or closed in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, firebase-cloud-messaging

So, am using [local_notifications](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_local_notifications) with [firebase messaging](https://pub.dev/packages/firebase_messaging) for notifications in my flutter app. I get the notifications when the app is opened, closed, and in background. However, the issue lies when I need to navigate to a certain screen by tapping on the notifications in these three instances.

**Opened State**: Navigating to a new screen works here for me because I have access to the current context. No issue here at all

**Background State** Tapping on the notification does nothing for me in this state. I guess its because I don't have access to its context. Also, onMessageOpenedApp or onMessage doesn't get triggered perhaps because am tapping on local notification not fcm's.

**Closed state:** Same issue with background state. Notification comes but does nothing when tapped.I need to move to a screen

So, what are the possible ways to approach this according to my need. I really need to get this done and am not making headway with the solutions online.

**MY CODE**

```
Future<void> _firebaseMessagingBackgroundHandler(RemoteMessage message) async {
  // If you're going to use other Firebase services in the background, such as Firestore,
  // make sure you call `initializeApp` before using other Firebase services.
  await Firebase.initializeApp();
  print("background message:" + message.data.toString());
  print('Handling a background message ${message.messageId}');
  await PushNotificationService().openNotificationPage(message.data);
}

class PushNotificationService{
  GraphQLClient? _apiClient;
  static String? _urlEndpoint;
  final FirebaseMessaging _firebaseMessaging = FirebaseMessaging.instance;
  FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin =
  FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin();
  Future initialize(context) async{
    print("initialised!");
    // Set the background messaging handler early on, as a named top-level function
    FirebaseMessaging.onBackgroundMessage(_firebaseMessagingBackgroundHandler);
    //listen for active messages
    FirebaseMessaging.instance
        .getInitialMessage()
        .then((RemoteMessage? message) async {
      if(message!=null){
        print("getInitialMsg" + message.data.toString());
        PushNotificationService().showNotification(message.data);
        openNotificationPage(message.data);
      }

    });
    const AndroidInitializationSettings initializationSettingsAndroid =
    AndroidInitializationSettings('@mipmap/ic_launcher');
    var initializationSettings =
    InitializationSettings(android: initializationSettingsAndroid);
    
    flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin.initialize(initializationSettings,
        onSelectNotification: selectNotification);
    FirebaseMessaging.onMessage.listen((RemoteMessage message) {
      print("onMessage: " + message.data.toString());
      PushNotificationService().showNotification(message.data);
      openNotificationPage(message.data);
    });

    FirebaseMessaging.onMessageOpenedApp.listen((RemoteMessage message) {
      print('A new onMessageOpenedApp event was published!');
      print("onMessageOpenedApp" + message.data.toString());
      openNotificationPage(message.data);
    });
  }


  Future showNotification(Map<String, dynamic> message) async {
    notification = PushNotification.fromJson(message);
    var androidPlatformChannelSpecifics = new AndroidNotificationDetails(
        'channel id',
        'channel name',
        'channel desc',
        importance: Importance.max,
        priority: Priority.high,
        playSound: true,
        timeoutAfter: 300000,
        enableVibration: true,
    );

    var platformChannelSpecifics =
    new NotificationDetails(android: androidPlatformChannelSpecifics);
    await flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin.show(
      0,
      notification!.pushNotification!.title,
      notification!.pushNotification!.content,
      platformChannelSpecifics,
      payload: 'Default_Sound',
    );
  }


  Future selectNotification(String? payload) async {
    await flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin.cancelAll();
    ///handle on select notification here
    if (payload != null) {
      print("payload" + payload.toString());
      openNotificationPage(json.decode(payload));
    }
    return null;

  }

  Future<void> openNotificationPage(Map<String, dynamic> map) async {
    await navigatorKey.currentState?.pushAndRemoveUntil(
      MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => PushNotificationDetailsPage()),
          (Route<dynamic> route) => false,
    );
    flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin.cancelAll();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you say that both **onMessage** and **onMessageOpenedApp** are not getting triggered, try to make sure that Flutter's binding is fully initialized by calling **WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized()** as the first call in your **void main()** method; I'm implementing FCM myself and for me all calls get triggered.

In my case, I have it like this:

```
void main() async {

  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  await Firebase.initializeApp(
    options: DefaultFirebaseOptions.currentPlatform,
  );

  // for background messages
  
  FirebaseMessaging.onBackgroundMessage(_firebaseMessagingBackgroundHandler);

  runApp(MyApp()) // my app code here
}
```

However, the **onMessageOpenedApp** method I have it inside my **MyApp** (which is a StatefulWidget) and I'm triggering things from inside the **initState**, as such:

```
/// inside MyApp's State:

@override
void initState() {
   setupInteractedMessage();
}

Future<void> setupInteractedMessage() async {
  RemoteMessage? initialMessage = await FirebaseMessaging.instance.getInitialMessage();

   // I handle any initial message coming in
   if (initialMessage != null) {
     _handleMessage(initialMessage);
   }

   // here is where I wire up the onMessageOpenedApp
   FirebaseMessaging.onMessageOpenedApp.listen(_handleMessage);
}

void _handleMessage(RemoteMessage message) {
  // here I do exactly what you're doing, I'm pushing my message into a service for app-wide consumption
}
```

See if that works out for you

Comment: are you tapping on the local notification's notification to trigger the onMessageAppOpened function?

Comment: No, I'm using the Firebase's Cloud Messaging Testing tool, as well as sending messages all the way from a Cloud Function using the FCM sdk in NodeJS. I get the messages all the way to my registered device.

Comment: okay. can you take a look at my code and see if it looks okay?